# Merge Rows Based on index Order U-SQL

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory, u-sql

I would love if someone could help me with this(updated):

I have a table that looks like this:

```
 Id      | name |          countryId           Sequence
--------+--------+------------------------+-------------------
 23     | John   |     102                |       1
 45     | Luis   |     102                |       1
 23     | Alex   |     102                |       2
 45     | James  |     102                |       2
```

And I want to merge similar ids into a single row using the ARRAY_AVG, so I use this query

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
    b.Id
    String.Join(",", ARRAY_AGG(b.name)) AS names
  FROM table AS b
  GROUP BY b.Id;
```

However doing this returns the following table but the name has been sorted on ASC

```
 Id      | names           
--------+--------+
 23     | Alex,John   
 45     | James,Luis
```

Since I want to create the names field as the name appears(based on index) so e.g John,Alex. so I tried this:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
    b.Id,
    String.Join(",", ARRAY_AGG(b.name).OrderBy(p => b.Sequence)) AS names
  FROM table AS b
  GROUP BY b.Id, b.Sequence;
```

But I get the results but this time, it is a bit different

```
 Id      | names           
--------+--------+
 23     | Alex
 23     | John   
 45     | James
 45     | Luis
```

The Sequence is ignored and the result isn't desired.

So I want to ask for the use the [ARRAG_AVG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/functions/aggregate/array-agg) properly in U-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Is your dummy data at the start of your question accurate?  If so, there is no difference in `countryId` values so there is no 'definitive' sort order for your `name` values when using your `OrderBy`.

Within SQL based languages, there is also no concept of data order when consuming or exporting data besides what is explicity specified in an `order by`.  If you don't have a suitable, definitive sort order as defined by the data, then you cannot guarantee consistency over multiple executions.

In order to get your sort order dependant on the position in the source file, you will need to either augment your source data to include an index value, or create a custom exporter that will scan through the file line by line and add the index on read.

---

What you have to ask yourself is why you even need to do this in the first place?  Concatenating strings like this into the one row is generally bad practice in set based languages and is very rarely appropriate.

Comment: I have updated the question to include a column where data with the same id have a unique sequence number

Comment: @umehoscar  I think your sequence is wrong?  Both rows for each `Id` value have the same `Sequence` value.  The values would need to either be unique within the file (essentially a row number) or unique within the group.

Comment: yea, sorry about that. I wasn't careful.

Comment: so you are saying that even with a column "Sequence" with a unique number for each data with the same Id, we still can't create merge rows?

Comment: @umehoscar You've included the `Sequence` column in your `group by`, so the output is going to be split by the unique `Sequence` values.  You should only be grouping by `Id`.  If you can't include the `OrderBy` without having to include the ordering column in the `group by` then no, you cannot achieve what you are trying to do.